# CSS first-child:before partly not working in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the code below, I have a row with 2 columns. Both columns have the exact same CSS code applied to them. However, `.leftMenu:first-child:before` is working perfectly fine on the first column, but `.pageContent:first-child:before` doesn't work at all.

When `.pageContent:first-child:before` is applied to the first column instead, it works perfectly fine again. What's going on here? And how do I fix it?

```css
.leftMenu {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
  border-left: 1px solid #070707;
}

.leftMenu:first-child:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  top:0px;
  left:0;
}

.pageContent {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  border-left: 1px solid #070707;
}

.pageContent:first-child:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 leftMenu">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 pageContent">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: both element aren't first child so it won't work. Why not simply remove :first-child since you have only 2 ?

Comment: _"When .pageContent:first-child:before is applied to the first column instead, it works perfectly fine again. What's going on here?"_ - you just found out what it means when an element is the first child of it parent ... `.leftMenu` is the first child of its parent (`.row`), so the selector matches - `.pageContent` however is not the first child (it is the second one), so that selector doesn't match ... simple as that.

Comment: Yes. I was assuming `:first-child` was selecting the first child inside the selector. That's what confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.pageContent` isn't the first-child of it's parent or `.row` in this case, instead it's the `last-child` so you can use

```
.pageContent:last-child:before
```

or

```
.pageContent:nth-child(2):before
```

When you use `classSelector:first-child` it will select element with that class if that element is also the first-child of its parent but not the first element with that class and not first child of that element.

```css
.leftMenu {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
  border-left: 1px solid #070707;
}

.leftMenu:first-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #0e0e0e);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}

.pageContent {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
  border-left: 1px solid #070707;
}

.pageContent:last-child:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #151515, #0a0a0a);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 leftMenu"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 pageContent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! That's working perfectly fine! Thanks a lot :) (Will mark as accepted when it's possible)

Answer (score -1):

`.pageContent:first-child` will match `.pageContent` elements that are the first child of their container. It will not work in your case.

If you want its first child, try `.pageContent > :first-child` instead.

Comment: I tried. That doesn't solve the issue. Not my downvote btw

Comment: What are you trying to do? `.pageContent:first-child` will never select anything in your html, but I don't see what you are trying to apply the `:before` to.

Comment: I was trying to insert a gradient design at the top of the second element. I assumed `:first-element` would select the first element inside the selector. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, then your `:first-child` (and now `:last-child`) do nothing in your current setup.